# How to run a local cargo-tool?

Tags: linux, rust, rust-cargo

Cargo tools like this https://github.com/bbqsrc/cargo-ndk can be installed. If I clone it, how can I run it? Can I also install it?

I tried

`RUST_LOG=trace cargo run -- -t arm64-v8a --bindgen build`

but I'm getting lots of errors

```
RUST_LOG=trace cargo run -- -t arm64-v8a --bindgen build
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/cargo-ndk -t arm64-v8a --bindgen build`
[2022-05-19T23:41:40Z TRACE cargo_ndk::cli] Args: ["arm64-v8a", "--bindgen", "build"]
[2022-05-19T23:41:40Z TRACE cargo_ndk::cli] is_release: false
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli] Using NDK at path: /opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cli] Exporting CARGO_NDK_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_PATH = "/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake"
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli] NDK API level: 21
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli] Building targets: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli] Building armeabi-v7a (armv7-linux-androideabi)
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cli] Exporting CARGO_NDK_ANDROID_TARGET = "armeabi-v7a"
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] Detected NDK version: Version { major: 22, minor: 1, patch: 7171670 }
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] cargo: /usr/local/rustup/toolchains/1.60.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] AR_armv7-linux-androideabi=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] CC_armv7-linux-androideabi=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] CXX_armv7-linux-androideabi=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang++
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_LINUX_ANDROIDEABI_AR=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_LINUX_ANDROIDEABI_LINKER=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] BINDGEN_EXTRA_CLANG_ARGS_armv7_linux_androideabi=/opt/android-sdk-linux/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] Args: ["arm64-v8a", "--bindgen", "build"]
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z DEBUG cargo_ndk::cargo] Working directory does not match manifest-path
error: no such subcommand: `arm64-v8a`
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli] If the build failed due to a missing target, you can run this command:
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli] 
[2022-05-19T23:41:41Z INFO  cargo_ndk::cli]     rustup target install armv7-linux-androideabi
```

I think the subcommands work a little different when the tool is not installed

Comment: When one runs a cargo subcommand, e.g. `cargo ndk ...`, the underlying binary is invoked with the same arguments.  So `cargo-ndk ndk ...`; notice in particular that the subcommand argument itself is forwarded (this enables tools like `cargo-edit` to use a single binary for all its subcommands).  Your `run` invocation is missing the `ndk` subcommand argument, however.  Not sure whether that's the root of your problem.

Comment: `cargo-ndk ndk build \n
This binary may only be called via `cargo ndk`.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing when you're in the folder:

```bash
cargo install --path .
```